# Prisma 2 - Map int column to enum

Tags: javascript, orm, prisma

At the database I've a column that is from type Integer that can only contain the following values Active = 1, Temporary=7, Deleted=10. Can these values be mapped from the server to a enum and the database is storing it within a integer column?

According to the documentation I can only use enums when the values are also stored as enums in the database.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to look at @map? Using your question as input, the enum would look like this.

```
enum YOU_ENUM {
    Active  @map(1)
    Temporary @map(7)
}
```

Comment: Error parsing attribute "@map": Expected a String value, but received numeric value `1`.

Comment: Thanks @armandopadilla. While it may not work for numbers, it works great for strings which is what I need it to do.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is impossible at the time of writing.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion, but was hoping that I had just missed it in the documentation. Thanks for the confirmation.